# Rewrite SQL query to optimize performance

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which takes around 2 seconds to load:

```
SELECT OUTPUT_VAL.NEXTVAL VAR1_R_ID,A.R_ID,A.VAR1,A.SEQU,A.OUTPUT,B.VAR1 DATATYPE_VAR1 
FROM
( 
    SELECT A.R_ID,A.VAR1,A.SEQU,A.OUTPUT,B.D_TYPE
    FROM
    (
        select A.R_ID, 2484 VAR1,1 SEQU, A.USER OUTPUT 
        from R_TB_1 A 
        WHERE A.R_ID BETWEEN 2457854437 AND 2458854437
        union all
        select A.R_ID, A.MEM_VAR1 VAR1,1 SEQU, MEM_OUTPUT OUTPUT 
        from R_TB_1 A 
        WHERE A.R_ID BETWEEN 2457854437 AND 2458854437
    ) A 
    LEFT JOIN VAR1_TABLE B 
        ON A.VAR1=B.VAR1
) A 
LEFT JOIN VAR1_TABLE B 
    ON A.D_TYPE=B.VAR1_NAME;
```

How can I rewrite it to improve performance?

Comment: if possible add table structure so that we can have better understanding of question

Comment: First, rewrite it to improve readability.

Comment: Then, it depends on a thousand factors unknown to us SO users: tables, number of records, existing indexes and triggers, etc, so it's very hard to actually help you here.

Comment: Please [edit] your question add the `create table` statements for the tables in question (including all indexs) and the execution plan for your query. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have a table `VAR1_TABLE` with at least three columns, `VAR1`, `D_TYPE` and `VAR1_NAME`... you select rows that have a `VAR1` column from another table, then you join with `VAR1_TABLE` on `MEM_VAR1 = VAR1`, and then you join again on `D_TYPE = VAR1_NAME`? Can you explain this part, since it makes no sense to me... why are you comparing `D_TYPE` to `VAR1_NAME`? Just because you can do it and the query runs without errors doesn't mean it makes sense.

Assuming the table R_TB_1 has many rows (you seem to be selecting 100,000 rows which is a small portion of the whole table), the `UNION ALL` means the table is scanned twice. You may be better off selecting just once, in a CTE, and then doing the union based on the CTE... if your version is at least Oracle 11.1. (By the way, state your Oracle version whenever you ask a question!) If you are on Oracle 10 or below, you will need subqueries like you have now.

Something like this:

```
with 
     Z ( R_ID, MEM_VAR1, USER, MEM_OUTPUT ) as (
       select R_ID, MEM_VAR1, USER, MEM_OUTPUT
       from   R_TB_1
       where  R_ID between 2457854437 and 2458854437
     ),
     A ( R_ID, VAR1, SEQU, OUTPUT ) as (
       select R_ID, 2484    , 1, USER
         from Z
       union all
       select R_ID, MEM_VAR1, 1, MEM_OUTPUT
         from Z 
     )
select  -- your joins from A to the other table here; A is defined in the WITH clause
```

Answer (score -3):

```
WITH temp AS (
SELECT OUTPUT_VAL.NEXTVAL VAR1_R_ID,A.R_ID,A.VAR1,A.SEQU,A.OUTPUT,B.VAR1 DATATYPE_VAR1 FROM

( 
SELECT A.R_ID,A.VAR1,A.SEQU,A.OUTPUT,B.D_TYPE FROM
(
SELECT A.R_ID, 2484 VAR1,1 SEQU, A.USER OUTPUT from R_TB_1 A WHERE A.R_ID BETWEEN 2457854437 AND 2458854437

union ALL

select A.R_ID, A.MEM_VAR1 VAR1,1 SEQU, MEM_OUTPUT OUTPUT from R_TB_1 A WHERE A.R_ID BETWEEN 2457854437 AND 2458854437
)
A LEFT JOIN VAR1_TABLE B ON A.VAR1=B.VAR1 ) 
A LEFT JOIN VAR1_TABLE B ON A.D_TYPE=B.VAR1_NAME
)
SELECT * FROM temp
```

Comment: When giving an answer could you provide more detail on why? Also indent your code with 4x spaces so it appears in a syntax coloured code block.

Comment: Could you explain any improvement between yours and original one? It seems you only put original SQL into CTE only, and it won't improve the performance